# Define a dictionary name within a function

Tags: python

I am writing a function that will take a parameter and, among other things, make a dictionary. I would like the dictionary's name to be based off the name of the input file. Say ht input file is `input.xml` , i would like the name of the dictionary to be `input`. Ideally I would use something like this:

```
def function(input):
    for x in y: list(get value)
    input[:4][key] = [value]
```

I am wondering if you know a better way to do this but what i am using now is an extra name in the function:

```
def function(input, dictname):
    for x in y: list(get value)
    dictname[key] = [value]
```

right now I am simply adding a second name to my function but am wondering if there is a way to do this to require fewer inputs.

---

Edit

---

I am including a longer version of the function I am using so you guys can get the context.  This uses a BioPython module to iterate through an XML file of hits. I am using [temp] to hold the hits for each query and then making a dictionary of for each set of query/hits. I would like this dictionary to be named the same as my input file.

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

def make_blast_dictionary(blastxml, maxhits, blastdict):
    temp=[]
    for record in NCBIXML.parse(open(blastxml):    
        for number, align in enumerate(record.alignments):
            if number == int(maxhits): break
            temp.append(str(align.title).split("|")[1])
    blastdict[str(record.query_id)] = [temp]
```

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't make much of a sense to me. Why not just return a dictionary from your function?

Comment: What is the name of a dictionary? Do you mean the name of a variable? If so, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please rewrite your question with more clarity.

Comment: Sorry to be the obnoxious one, but why do you want this? This sounds like something I would _never_ want.

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: what a reply! if the output of my function is a dictionary, I would like the dictionary's name to be the same as the input file it was created from. In the case above the function will call the input file (an xml file of blast results) and return a dictionary of hits. I would like this dictionary to have the same name as the blast output and I thought the easiest way to do this is to slice the inputfile name although this is neither elegant nor kosher. The second example is just showing that I can define the name of the dicitonary explicitly and the function works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about named variables is that you can call them whatever you like. It's best to name them specific to the context you're using them with.

It would be a better move to simply *return* a dictionary from your method, instead.

Answer (score 1):

The other respondents are legitimately concerned about *why* you would want to do this or whether you *should* do this.  That being said, here is *how* you could do it:

```
import os.path

def function(filename):
    d = {'red': 10, 'blue': 20}
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    globals()[name] = d

function('input.xml')
print input
```

Comment: you must also make sure the file name does not begin with a number.

Comment: @Rotem The above code still works with a name beginning with a number.  Dynamically created names tend to be looked-up dynamically as well (if you knew the name in advance you could have assigned directly).

Comment: That's cool, did not know that you could dynamically assign an otherwise invalid name, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
def make_name(input):
    return = input.split('.')[0]

def function(input):
    """Note: this function is incomplete and assumes additional parameters are in your original script
    """
    for x in y: list(get value)
        dict_name[key] = [value]
    return dict_name

def make_dict(input): 
    dict_name = make_name(input)
    dict_name = {}
    dict_name = function(input)
    return dict_name
```

Is this what you need?